# Google Maps shows different location, compared to input

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Google Maps works perfectly fine when it is allowed to display on the main view.

But, as I use a new Sub the location of the maps is wrong and does not seem to change even with the change in the latitude and longitude values.

Code Snippet:

```
 import UIKit
 import GoogleMaps

 class MainVC: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var mapSubView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(13.009047, longitude: 77.652949, zoom: 6)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(self.mapSubView.bounds, camera: camera)

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true

    self.mapSubView = mapView


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.009047, longitude: 77.652949)
    marker.title = "Bangalore"
    marker.snippet = "India"
    marker.map = mapView
}

}
```

App Screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Try zooming out and check if your marker is being created in the right position

Comment: No. The marker is not visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your code:-

```
 mapSubView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.009047, longitude: 77.652949), zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
```

`GoogleMaps` camera just defines the orientation of the map along with the properties such as how much zoom do you want, whats the target of Zoom etc..For more details about this function and what the parameters represent CMD+CLICK on this function to go to its documentaion

**EDIT:**
The above code was adding a new **GMSMapView**, using code in the **View Controller** above the already existing **GMSMapView** that was configured using the **IBOutlet**

Updated Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapSubView: GMSMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    mapSubView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapSubView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.009047, longitude: 77.652949), zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)


    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.009047, longitude: 77.652949)
    marker.title = "Bangalore"
    marker.snippet = "India"
    marker.map = mapSubView
}
```

Google Maps iOS SDK Docs: [GMSCameraPosition Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_camera_position.html#a5c177880230158fc88a97248ee79f46b)

Google Maps iOS SDK Docs: 
[GMSMarker Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#af25ba38813fea5f65d99eca237a062f8)

Comment: Thanks @Dravidian. But can you please explain what is happening here? Moreover, my marker is not also displayed

Answer (score 0):

Culprit here is:

```
marker.map = mapView
```

Replace it with:

```
marker.map = self.mapSubView
```

Also, no need to create *mapView*.

Here is complete code, this should work:

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(13.009047, longitude: 77.652949, zoom: 6)
    self.mapSubView.camera = camera
    self.mapSubView.myLocationEnabled = true

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.009047, longitude: 77.652949)
    marker.title = "Bangalore"
    marker.snippet = "India"
    marker.map = self.mapSubView
```

**Important Changes**:

```
self.mapSubView.camera = camera
marker.map = self.mapSubView
```